# IndexError: list index out of range (in query results)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am having problems understanding how to work with query results. I asked about half a dozen questions about this but I still do not understand. I copy from previous code and I make it work somehow but since I don't understand the underlying concept the code breaks down if I make a minor change. I would really appreciate if you could tell me how you visualize what is happenning here and explain it to me. Thank you.

```
class ReceiveEmail(InboundMailHandler):
    def receive(self, message):
        logging.info("Received email from %s" % message.sender)
        plaintext = message.bodies(content_type='text/plain')
        for text in plaintext:
            txtmsg = ""
            txtmsg = text[1].decode()
            logging.info("Body is %s" % txtmsg)
            logging.info("CC email is %s" % ((message.cc).split(",")[1]))            

        query = User.all()           
        query.filter("userEmail =",  ((message.cc).split(",")[1])) 
        results = query.fetch(1)                   

        for result in results:                     
            result.userScore += 1                  

        um = results[0]                            
        um.userScore = result.userScore            
        um.put()
```

In this code, as I understand it, the query takes the second email address from the cc list and fetches the result.

Then I increment the userScore by 1.

Next, I want to update this item in Datastore so I say

```
        um = results[0]                            
        um.userScore = result.userScore            
        um.put()
```

But this gives an index out of range error:

```
um = results[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Why? I am imagining that `results[0]` is the zeroeth item of the results. Why is it out of range? Only thing I can think of is that, the list may be `None`. But I don't understand why. It must have the 1 item that was fetched.

Also, if I try to test for the first email address by changing the index from [1] to [0]

```
query.filter("userEmail =",  ((message.cc).split(",")[0]))
```

then I don't get the `IndexError`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

See comments:

```
(message.cc).split(",")[0])
```

left a space in front of the emails (starting with the second email), so the query was not matching them;

```
>>> cc.split(",")
['cc12@example.com', ' cc13@example.com', ' cc13@example.com']
```

adding a space after comma fixed the problem:

```
>>> listcc = cc.split(", ")
>>> listcc
['cc12@example.com', 'cc13@example.com', 'cc13@example.com']
>>>
```

Comment: How sure are you that there are any results to fetch in the first place?

Comment: Yes, good question. I am sending an email from the Dev Console Inbound Mail with cc field that includes `user11@example.com` and `cc777@example.com`. I make sure these 2 emails are already in the database so that the query can fetch them. But I just tried again neither index 0 nor 1 is working now. Can you suggest any ways to check what the query sees? Thanks.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: You may be right; the query appears to fail: if results:
            for result in results:
                result.userScore += 1           
            um = results[0]
            um.userScore = result.userScore
            um.put()
        else:
            logging.info("query failed")

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: Thanks for the clue! `((message.cc).split(",")[0]))` left a space in front of the emails, so the query was not matching them; so adding a space after comma fixed the problem: `((message.cc).split(", ")[0]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand the code break it down and look at it piece by piece:

```
class ReceiveEmail(InboundMailHandler):
    def receive(self, message):
        logging.info("Received email from %s" % message.sender)

        # Get a list of CC addresses.  This is basically a for loop.
        cc_addresses = [address.strip() for address in message.cc.split(",")]
        # The CC list goes with the message, not the bodies.
        logging.info("CC email is %s" % (cc_addresses))

        # Get and iterate over all of the *plain-text* bodies in the email.
        plaintext = message.bodies(content_type='text/plain')
        for text in plaintext:
            txtmsg = ""
            txtmsg = text[1].decode()
            logging.info("Body is %s" % txtmsg)

        # Setup a query object.
        query = User.all()
        # Filter the user objects to get only the emails in the CC list.
        query.filter("userEmail IN",  cc_addresses)
        # But, only get at most 10 users.
        users = query.fetch(10)

        logging.info('Got %d user entities from the datastore.' % len(users))

        # Iterate over each of the users increasing their score by one.
        for user in users:
            user.userScore += 1

        # Now, write the users back to the datastore.
        db.put(users)
        logging.info('Wrote %d user entities.' % len(users))
```

I would make an adjustment to your model structure.  When you create the User entity, I would set the key_name to the email address.  You will be able to make your queries much more efficient.

Some references:

- [List Comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).
- [Query Object](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass.html).
- [db.put()](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions.html#put).

Comment: Hello Robert: Thanks for this detailed explanation. This was very helpful. I studied the three links that you referenced. Special thanks for modifying and organizing the code; it makes much more sense now. In the case of `put()` I understand that we fetched 10 rows from the table `User` by filtering `cc_addresses` from the `userEmail` column. Then we updated the `userScore` and by `db.put(users)` we wrote the rows that we updated back to the datastore. Looking at the Development Console's Datastore Viewer; I see that, app engine knows to update just the `userScore`.

Comment: It actually updates all properties on the entities, but because we only changed `userScore` it is the only property changed.